# How do you access your heroku database (specifically postgres)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, heroku

When I am developing locally, I'll just run a

```
rails c
```

and I can fire of queries at the console.

However, how can I query and access my postgres database that is up on heroku?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can run `heroku run rails c --app <appname>`. I will also add, if you want to view your database, you can make use of PG Commander https://eggerapps.at/pgcommander/ which actually automatically parses all the credentials out for you.

If you want to do this, run `heroku config --app <appname>` and then copy the `DATABASE_URL`. After you've done this, create a new favourite in your PG Commander and you'll see that it has already automatically filled in all the credentials based on what was in your clipboard.

Comment: the --app <appname> is optional in case you have multiple apps attached

Comment: Thanks! That begs me to ask... if I can do this... why am I not able to run 'heroku run psql databasename' like I can locally?

Comment: well you can actually `heroku pg:psql` as per https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-postgresql